# Grunt contrib sass NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, grunt-contrib-watch

I recently updated my Ruby to v1.9.3 and updated sass and compass. Now when I run the `grunt-contrib-scss` task I receive the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm not an expert in **compass** and **scss** so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Does it happen if you compile directly from Sass? What about Compass? What version of Sass, Compass, Grunt and Zurb?

Comment: I just had a very similar issue with sass-3.4.0.rc.1, after removing it and installing 3.3.5 it started working again.

Answer (score 7):

You probably used `--pre` option to update Sass, and it installed the `3.4.0.rc.1` version, **which is** the problem.

Uninstall the `3.4.0.rc.1` version, and use the `3.3.10` one :

```
gem uninstall sass --version 3.4.0.rc.1
gem install sass --version 3.3.10
```

Comment: This may be fixed in 3.4.0.rc3: https://github.com/sass/sass/commit/84b66ac023555bd471effeba5b9d667769aabf79